# Can anyone figure out why I'm receiving the an error for my code? I've installed tidyverse and dplyr so I don't understand

Tags: r, excel, function, rename, percentage

Here's my codes:

```
subins %<>% 
  rename(
    genus = geNus,
    family = familyy, 
    weight = weight.of.insect, 
    body_length = body.length.of.insevct, 
    tarsus_width = tarsus.with )
```

It says it could not find the function `%<>%` so tried `%>%` but still no luck.

Comment: I think `%<>%` is in package `magrittr`.

Comment: Just added that, thanks! Although now it's saying it cant find function "rename"

Comment: Well, `rename()` should be in dplyr. Make sure that dplyr is loaded using `library(dplyr)` or `library(tidyverse)`.

Comment: I'm a beginner in R so everything is baffling to me but it's just worked! Thank you so much!!

Comment: As a beginner, note that there is a big difference between installing packages (usually, done using `install.packages()`), which needs to be done only once normally, and loading packages using `library()`, which needs to be done every time you start a new R session. Good luck on your R journey then :-)

Comment: Just as an aside, %<>% and most of the other fancy pipes from magrittr are "exotic" operators that are not commonly used. They have some limited utility when doing ad-hoc analysis but the more you rely on syntax like this, the harder it will be for other people to understand and reproduce your code. As I beginner, I encourage you to focus on base R syntax first, and then add dplyr and other tidyverse functions. Tidyverse has many cool features but also makes use of a ton of design tricks that diverge from the normal syntax and mechanics of the language.

Comment: I'll definitely make a note of that! Thank you M.Papenberg and bcarlsen !!